# Logo not appearing on metamask

Tags: metamask, private-blockchain, blockchain-fork

I have added native coin of my own blockchain on metamask but logo is not appearing on metamask. [image]

Answer (score 1):

[Metamask docs](https://metamask.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360059582151-How-to-add-a-token-logo) have an answer for you:

> The token search box and the auto-detect functions are a part of a centralized solution. We encourage developers to use the EIP-747 method, which you can find in the technical documentation below:

> https://docs.metamask.io/guide/registering-your-token.html#registering-tokens-with-users

> In the above link, you can find instructions on how to integrate the wallet_watchAsset API as defined in EIP-747 without having to create code, and also a more advanced code example that includes the option to set a logo or icon for your token. This will let your users add your token to their MetaMask wallet, and see it, easily.

Comment: This answer is for custom tokens, which is good, but does not answer the question made by @Brijesh.

He asked for the icon of a custom Eth-compatible network that has a main system token with an icon. That icon is not showing at all.

Answer (score 0):

MetaMask *only* auto-displays **network** and **native token** logos by default for *reliable top assets*. This requires being ranked in the top 50 on CoinMarketCap and is [centrally managed by MetaMask](https://support.metamask.io/hc/en-us/articles/360059582151-How-to-add-a-token-logo). See this [community post](https://community.metamask.io/t/adding-logo-icon-to-a-new-evm-network-in-metamask/25589).