# How to add the Native Coin Blockchain logo in MetaMask (visible for public) for an EVM Layer 1 pre EIP 1559 Blockchain

Tags: metamask

I got a great questions and i can't find any answer about this, neither does the MM Support have an answer for that.

MetaMask support only points to the EIP-747 method via wallet_watchAsset API. However, I don't want to add a token logo for my private own wallet, but I want to add our Native Coin logo for the blockchain. So that everyone who integrates this blockchain into MM will automatically see the Native Coin logo.

NETWORK NAME
Proof Of Memes Mainnet

NEW RPC URL
https://rpc.pomchain.io

CHAIN ID
18159

SYMBOL
POM

BLOCK EXPLORER URL
https://memescan.io

[image: Thats the Native Coin "POM" of the Blockchain and i need MM to add the Logo for public]

How to get support by MM for that or where to i need to register the Blockchain, so that MM will show the native coin & Blockchain Logo.

The MM Support Sites doesn't provide an answer for that.

p.s. it's already registered at Chainlist: https://chainlist.org/chain/18159

Thanks in advance!

Have a nice day

Comment: This is only supported for top networks and tokens, see my answer on duplicate question here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/151701/29866

Answer (score 0):

With this code:

```
const tokenAddress = '0xd00981105e61274c8a5cd5a88fe7e037d935b513';
const tokenSymbol = 'TUT';
const tokenDecimals = 18;
const tokenImage = 'http://placekitten.com/200/300';

try {
  // wasAdded is a boolean. Like any RPC method, an error may be thrown.
  const wasAdded = await ethereum.request({
    method: 'wallet_watchAsset',
    params: {
      type: 'ERC20', // Initially only supports ERC20, but eventually more!
      options: {
        address: tokenAddress, // The address that the token is at.
        symbol: tokenSymbol, // A ticker symbol or shorthand, up to 5 chars.
        decimals: tokenDecimals, // The number of decimals in the token
        image: tokenImage, // A string url of the token logo
      },
    },
  });

  if (wasAdded) {
    console.log('Thanks for your interest!');
  } else {
    console.log('Your loss!');
  }
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

You can do it through interface here:

https://metamask.github.io/Add-Token/#edit

Comment: Thats the EIP-747 method via wallet_watchAsset API.
I'm not talking about an Token.

I'm talking about to add the Logo of a native Coin of a Blockchain. There's no contract for an native blockchain coin.

Comment: The only possibility I can see or find so far is that MetaMask has to completely support the network and add it to the application, like MM already did with kind of Blockchains like: Arbitrum One, Aurora Mainnet, Avalanche Network C-Chain and so on.

But how can I make that happen?

Comment: I think that this isn't up to you.